# Error in formula on Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

Well, I tried to make a formula on Excel 2010 in order to get flexible results.

The idea is to count cell written less cells empty, so the formula should be: 
`=CONTAR(C10:C69) - CONTAR.BLANCO(C10:C[VALUE])`
Where the Value is `8 + the result of CONTAR(C10:C69)`.
The real formula actually extends more than this, but I got stuck at this step.
That being said, how can I produce the same result using Visual Basic to actualize the list every time excel is modified?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: thank you for the correction

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use Index to return a reference to the range from C10 to C[Value]

```
=COUNT(C10:C69)-COUNTBLANK(C10:INDEX(C:C,8+COUNT(C10:C69)))
```

(I hope I have got the correct equivalent functions for Contar etc.)

Comment: Equivalent functions are corrects, and INDEX is INDICE in spanish but this functions makes other things.
Anyway, I changed my mind and I found another formula easier get the same result!
Thank you anyway!